# what is a default color of the bacground of command line terminal

Tags: command-line, colors, default

Hey kinda of a lame qustion, but I just update my Ubuntu to biolinux and the color of my command line terminal got changed, its kinda annoying cause I'm used to dark purple color, Im trying to create the same custom collor but I dont know the exact numbers, please help

Comment: If you are using the default Ubuntu theme, selecting "Use color from system theme" should give you what you want. Either way in my system I got as the bg color `#2F0A24` and text color `#D1D5CD` (using GPick, so may not be very accurate...)